# Получить тело функции

Tags: python

Есть функция, внутри нее какой то код, так вот как программно получить этот код который находиться внутри функции в виде строки или любом другом виде, главное получить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужен исходный код, то поможет функция [getsource()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsource) модуля [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html), а если байткод, то функция [dis()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis) из одноимённого модуля.

Answer (score 0):

Через атрибут:

```
FUNCTION.__code__
```

Если атрибут отсутствует то код получить нельзя.